# POST requests not working on production in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I moved my application from localhost to dedicated server. On localhost everything was working fine. However, I discovered that I can't login/register on production. Even when I don't fill all required inputs and press submit button, there's no validation, no old() values. To be strict - nothing in code has been changed since I moved app to production.

Just to test what's going on I changed form action in login view to "/test" and when I added route (POST) to "/test", I got 404. However - Route::get for "/test" was working!

When I added

```
Route::any('/test', function (Request $r) {
        dd($r);
});
```

after posting through form action I got Request { ... #method: "GET" ... }

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: do you have Auth::routes(); in your web.php ?

Comment: Yes, of course. As I mentioned I even created new post route with new controller just to test POST request. After submitting request is treated as GET.

Comment: Do you have any 301, 302 or 303 redirects configured?

Comment: have a look at your log file `storage/logs/laravel.....` do you see any errors?

Comment: I don't have redirects. Signup/login feature has been added by `php artisan make:auth`. No error logs in log file. One more thing. When I POST a request to `password/reset` on localhost everything is processing fine, but on production I have `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. Once again - in my web.php there's  `Auth::routes();` line

Comment: Can show the chrome injection and the form action. From what your error means Laravel can't match the method in your route. Do share your production server link to let us help you test.

Comment: Can you try running `php artisan route:cache` and see if it works?

Comment: Just a  guess can you do this Route::post('/test', function (Request $r) {
        dd($r);
});

Comment: Ok guys, I just created fresh laravel project on the same server with `php artisan make:auth` and I got the same issue! So this is a matter of a Linode server, but I have no idea how. This is URL to fresh laravel project where /login and /register POSTs requests are not working also: `http://139.162.219.73`

Comment: @feyen01 - there is something in your javascript preventing the form from posting. If you disable javascript on that page the form posts. I just tested it.